# PHP invoking Expect Script (Works running the script through SSH, but on invoked with PHP)

Tags: php, ssh, centos, httprequest, expect

I have a UBNT Toughswitch and am trying to remotely turn off poe power with my cell phone with php and scripts. I do this with similar scripts with UBNT mFi. The script works fine if I SSH into the server (w/ root, only user I ever setup) and run it in the location its in. I checked all the R/W/E boxes on the script and php code in case it was a php permission issue. So here is the scripts:

PHP to invoke the script with a http get request:

```
    <?php

    system ( "./tsport3-24-off.sh" );

    ?>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    window.close();

    </script>
```

Here is the Expect Script:

```
    #!/usr/bin/expect
    set timeout 30

    spawn ssh shane@$ip
        expect {
            "*assword:*" {
                send "$password\r"
                expect {
                    "*assword:*" {
                            close
                            continue
                            }
                    "*#*" {
                        send "grep -v 'switch.port.3.poe=48' /var/tmp/system.cfg > /var/tmp/tmpsystem.cfg; mv /var/tmp/tmpsystem.cfg /var/tmp/system.cfg\r"
                        expect {
                            "*not found*" {
                                    close
                                    }
                            "*#*" {
                                send "save && reboot\r"
                                interact
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

It will get through everything until the save && reboot portion and won't do that when invoked via php. Through SSH, it works fine. I also tried save and reboot with 2 different commands in case it didn't like &&, and isolated that into a separate script to make sure that is where its at. It's like php just refuses to send save && reboot for some reason like a permission problem, but it's sending it to a different device trough ssh so it doesn't make sense to me. This one is to turn off poe 24v on port 3. I have others for on (24/48) and reboot that all work without php, but not with php.

Answer (score 0):

Not a 100% answer, but it works.

If I add another save && reboot like so:

```
    expect "*#*"
    send "save && reboot/r"
    expect "*#*"
    send "save && reboot/r"
```

It doesn't error out when run by the php script, probably does if I run it normal, but that was never my intention anyway. Think it's a timing issue or it's picking up an extra *#* somewhere when being run by php.